# How to convert json datetime to datetime in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I store in database a datetime in json format, and i need to reconvert it in datetime when needed.

Once decoded, it is an associated array:

```
[date] => 2021-05-20 17:00:00.000000
[timezone_type] => 3
[timezone] => UTC
```

I'm a little confuse about how to turn this one into a datetime with the correct timezone...

I have found that

Timezones can be one of three different types in DateTime objects:

```
1. Type 1: A UTC offset, such as in new DateTime("17 July 2013 -0300");
2. Type 2; A timezone abbreviation, such as in new DateTime("17 July 2013 GMT");
3. Type 3: A timezone identifier, such as in new DateTime( "17 July 2013", new DateTimeZone("Europe/London"));
```

But i'm not sure how i can apply this with my current data. I have 3 parameters, and all of these solutions use only 2 params

Here is the code i wish to use:

```
/**
 * @return array|null
 * @throws JsonException
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function getContext(): ?array
{
    $context = json_decode($this->context, true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
    foreach ($context as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value) && isset($value['date'], $value['timezone_type'], $value['timezone'])){
            $date = new DateTime($value['date'] . '-' . $value['timezone_type'] );
            $context[$key] = $date;
            $context[$key] = $date;
        }
    }
    return array_unique($context);
```

It should display `18h00`, but without timezone it display `17h00` and with timezone it display `20h00`

Comment: Timezone type doesn't seem relevant. Can you show your code and explain what issue you ran into when converting this into a date object?

Comment: i edited the question add what you asked for

Comment: `new DateTime($value['date'] . '-' . $value['timezone_type'] )` will make the timezone type be interpreted as an actual UTC offset.

Comment: And why do you expect `18:00` to be the value?

Comment: because the datetime wich was jsonified was 18h (it was retrieve from a database using doctrine)

Comment: I find that hard to believe. JSON doesn't convert time zones. If the value has `17:00` and `UTC`, then that's the object that was encoded as JSON. If the DateTime object's time zone was changed *before* JSON encoding, that's entirely different.

Comment: I double check and it seems you are right. The datetime is 17h when jsonified. It came from a missing clone date that change the date minus 1h. I tested it successfuly.

Comment: You would need to show how you save the date/time as it stored it as UTC but if it was originally 18:00 then the original tz must have been +1.

Comment: So, anyway, just use `timezone` instead of `timezone_type` when recreating the object and you should be fine.

Answer (score -1):

What you have is the result of feeding `json_encode()` with a `DateTimeInterface` object. The time zone type is an internal field of no interest:

```
$dt = new DateTime('2021-05-19 20:30:00 +0200');
echo json_encode($dt), PHP_EOL;
$dt = new DateTime('2021-05-19 20:30:00 CEST');
echo json_encode($dt), PHP_EOL;
$dt = new DateTime('2021-05-19 20:30:00 Europe/Berlin');
echo json_encode($dt), PHP_EOL;
```

```
{"date":"2021-05-19 20:30:00.000000","timezone_type":1,"timezone":"+02:00"}
{"date":"2021-05-19 20:30:00.000000","timezone_type":2,"timezone":"CEST"}
{"date":"2021-05-19 20:30:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Berlin"}
```

You can ignore that and just build a string with the two other values as in my example.